# Delete link unable to get the exact id of item to delete

Tags: php, html, mysql

I don't get it when my coding not manage to get the id of item selected, to be deleted, which I believe that should getting the correct id. I displayed all of my item using coding below. Each item displayed have their own **delete** and **edit** link.

```
<?php           
    $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct LEFT JOIN productcategory ON tblproduct.prodCat = productcategory.catID ORDER BY tblproduct.id DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql_select);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            ?>
            <li>
                <h3><?php echo $row['prodName']; ?></h3>
                <div>
                    <img src="<?php echo "user_images/".$row['prodImg']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <p>Code : <?php echo $row['prodCode']; ?></p>
                <p>Price : RM<?php echo $row['prodPrice']; ?></p>
                <p>Category : <?php echo $row['prodCat']; ?></p>
                <p>Description : <?php echo $row['prodDesc']; ?></p>
                <span>
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="editform.php?edit_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="click for edit" onclick="return confirm('sure to edit ?')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> 
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="function.php?delete_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="click for delete" onclick="return confirm('sure to delete ?')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Delete</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Refer to above code, when I click **delete** link, the item id is always return `1` and my database only have **two** record which id start from `17`

Comment: please check the rendered html source ,whether its printing actual id or not

right click -> inspect element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The column id is ambiguous and can come from **productcategory** too. So you need to do something like below

```
$sql_select = "SELECT tblproduct.id as product_id,* FROM tblproduct LEFT JOIN productcategory ON tblproduct.prodCat = productcategory.catID ORDER BY tblproduct.id DESC";
```

HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="function.php?delete_id=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" title="click for delete" onclick="return confirm('sure to delete ?')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Delete</a>
 </span>
```

Comment: seems to be a cause.nice catch +1.

Comment: I am getting error **Trying to get property of non-object** on the line `if ($result->num_rows > 0){` when I replaced my sql query using yours.